# GetWindowRect() not returning a rect

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a bit of C# code that looks like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);
Rect rect = Rect.Zero;
NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rect);
```

However, when I run this code, the `rect` variable is still equal to `Rect.Zero` (top/bottom/left/right are all zero), even though `GetWindowRect()` returned success. This sequence of function calls works just fine when implemented in C++, but not when called in C# through P/Invoke.

I am certain I am calling `GetWindowRect()` properly; that is not the problem. The problem is that `GetWindowRect()` is always returning a `RECT` of `{0,0,0,0}`, no matter how I change the function call or how I define the P/Invoke.

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/getwindowrect.html

Comment: Could you show the definition of `Rect` ?

Comment: You did not check for errors. Why not?

Comment: Your `Rect` class needs to be a struct.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the handle I was passing into `GetWindowRect()` was not a valid `HWND`.

Comment: But you said that `GetWindowRect` returned success. If the `HWND` were invalid, then `GetWindowRect` should have returned failure.

Comment: @RaymondChen I run into the same issue as well using similar code. Using `out` in C# causes the program to crash, while using `ref` produces a null reference error.

Comment: Turns out using out produces a double pointer. The `RECT` class defined in C# needs to be a struct rather than a class, or you can pass it to the interop function byval.